# How do Bitwise Operators work?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

So I was going through some problems at codewars.com and I came across a problem about basic encryption (https://www.codewars.com/kata/basic-encryption/javascript). The goal is to get a string value and shift it x values to the right on the ASCII chart.

here was my initial solution:

```
function encrypt(text, rule) {
    let res = ''
  for(let i = 0; i<text.length; i++) {
    res += (String.fromCharCode(text.charCodeAt(i)+rule))
  }
  return res
};
```

However, it didn't pass all of the tests, so I looked at the solutions and this is what got me to pass the tests:

```
function encrypt(text, rule) {
    let res = ''
  for(let i = 0; i<text.length; i++) {
    res += (String.fromCharCode(text.charCodeAt(i)+rule & 255))
  }
  return res
};
```

All because of adding that `& 255`, Could someone explain to me what has really changed by adding that to make my code valid?

Comment: hint, an ascii character can't have a charcode greater than 255

Comment: Actually, an ASCII character can't have a code greater than 127. But in most cases, people say "ASCII" when they mean "8 bit". The problem clearly states that the range of valid characters is 0-255, so they expect than you will take any character in that range, and return only characters in that range. `& 255` will make sure of that, as would have `% 256`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As somebody said above, your valid range of characters is from 0 to 255. There are many ways to valid this condition but `bitwise and` looks like shortest one.

> Bitwise AND returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of both operands are ones.

For example:

`1111 & 0000` would return `0000`

`1111 & 0001` would return `0001`

`1111 & 0010` would return `0010`

`1111 & 0100` would return `0100`

But, as you can read in the docs:

> Bitwise operators perform their operations on such binary representations, but they return standard JavaScript numerical values.

If you use this operator on integer you would get integer instead of binary.

In your case, using `number & 255` makes you sure that end value would be in range from 0 to 255.

You can read more about bitwise operators [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).